# Waiting for ajax response append and load content before firing function

Tags: ajax, image, resize, load, append

Hi i got a project where i get posts from server with ajax post, them i detect images in appended posts and resize them based on their ratio using a function.

The problem is when i append new post's and try to fire the function, it detects the images as size (height and width) 0, cause the image ain`t loaded yet. I searched, but i won't found any answer, there is a way to detect if all images in ajax response (where it contains, other elements) have been loaded using .onload or another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

```
                                   **Update**
```

I figure it out:

Checking for img elements length inside ajax response:

```
$("#yourelement").append(html);
var $dialog = $(html);
imglength = $dialog.find("img").length;
```

Add a count++ on every img loaded, and check if its equal to img length:

```
n_images = 0;
$("#yourelement img").on('load', function(){ // check for every new image loaded in # 
n_images++;

if (n_images == imglength) {
//alert(imglength); // I used to verify if it works
yourfunction(); // will fire when all new images have been appended and loaded
}

});
```